# custom kernel function in R for SVM model based on RBF

Tags: r, kernel, svm

currently I am using the library of **e1071** in R to train a SVM model with RBF kernel, for example, calling the SVM function with the following parameters:

the question here is is there any possibility to further custom the RBF kernel in R? what I want to do is to add an additional calculation to the original RBF kernel, such as:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Xi and Xj are two objects representing the time series at absolute timestampts Ti and Tj:

any idea is welcome and thank you :)

---

*Hi , thanks for the answer from @lejlot, here I just edit the formula based on his solution , is it right :)

```
denote ai = (xi,ti) and bi = (xi, 1/sqr(g)*ti)

K(ai, aj) = exp(-g*||xi-xj||^2) exp(-(ti-tj)^2) =
      = exp(-g*||xi-xj||^2 -(ti-tj)^2) =
      = exp(-g*||xi-xj||^2 -g(1/sqr(g)*ti-1/sqr(g)*tj)^2) =
      = exp(-g*(||xi-xj||^2 + (1/sqr(g)*ti-1/sqr(g)*tj)^2)) =
      = exp(-g*(||xi-xj||^2 + (1/sqr(g)*ti-1/sqr(g)*tj)^2)) =
      = exp(-g*(||bi-bj||^2)) = RBF(bi, bj)*
```

*but still, another question here is you said that concatenate ti (multiplied by 1/gamma) to the data representation, but how?

Assumed that the the matrix of X contains 4 features, such as below:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4
3  5  6  7  
4  3  2  4
8  5  2  2
3  2  1  0
9  9  3  2
```

regarding to time-stamp value, since each row have same vale, the responding matrix could be:

```
t1 t2 t3 t4
1  1  1  1  
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4
5  5  5  5
```

in the package of e1071, the svm function just contains x as input matrix, how we could also include a time-stamp matrix for modelling? I do not know if this is a simple or stupid question, but now it makes me crazy :(

thank you :)

Comment: This is not a valid kernel. Maybe you meant ... x exp( -(ti-tj)^2 ) ?

Comment: hi , thank you , yes! you are right, i just corrected the description :), do you have any suggestion for it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write custom kernel for svm in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633265/write-custom-kernel-for-svm-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is not a generic solution, but in your particular case there is no need for a custom kernel, lets denote ai = (xi,ti) and bi = (xi, 1/sqrt(g)*ti)

```
K(ai, aj) = exp(-g*||xi-xj||^2) exp(-(ti-tj)^2) =
          = exp(-g*||xi-xj||^2 -(ti-tj)^2) =
          = exp(-g*||xi-xj||^2 -g(1/sqrt(g)*ti-1/sqrt(g)*tj)^2) =
          = exp(-g*(||xi-xj||^2 + (1/sqrt(g)*ti-1/sqrt(g)*tj)^2)) =
          = exp(-g*(||xi-xj||^2 + (1/sqrt(g)*ti-1/sqrt(g)*tj)^2)) =
          = exp(-g*(||bi-bj||^2)) = RBF(bi, bj)
```

since

```
||bi-bj||^2 = SUM_k (bik-bjk)^2 = SUM_k (xik-xjk)^2 + (ti-tj)^2
```

so all you have to do is concatenate ti (multiplied by 1/sqrt(gamma)) to your data representation and apply regular RBF kernel.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the answer, if I understand your idea correctly, the bi = (xi, 1/g*ti) should be bi = (xi, 1/sqr(g)*ti) :),

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but based on your idea, how can we implement it in R ? you mean just adding the value of ti to the original matrix xi, for example, such as （x1,x2,x3,x4,1/sqrt(g)*t1,1/sqrt(g)*t2,1/sqrt(g)*t3,1/sqrt(g‌​)*t4, even thought here t1=t2=t3=t4. then just apply the svm model with RBF normally: really looking forward to your answer, and thank you !

Comment: all you have to do is concatenate T as a new column. I do not know why you are replicating it, there is no point - simply append corresponding t to each vector. You have your data X which is N x D (N-number of samples, D-features) and you have T which is N x 1 (one timestamp per data point), just concatenate it to get N x (D+1) matrix (remembering to rescale T by 1/sqrt(gamma)) and run regular rbf.

Comment: Hi , thank you very much for the detailed information :)